# Refrencing font and mobile responsivness HTML EMAIL

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-email

I need open sans to load even if the device doesn't have it downloaded. I also need my email to be mobile responsive, and when loading on a phone or in Gmail it looks all wrong. However, if I open it in the email app on my computer, it looks great. What do I change in the code below to make it work, it's driving me crazy!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .tutorial4 {            
      align: left;
      width: 600px;
      padding-left: 11px;
      font-family: "Open Sans";
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: regular;
    }

    .tutorial {
      display: inline-block;
      align: left;
      width: 350px;
      padding: 60px 11px 10px;
      font-family: "Open Sans";
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: bolder;
    }

    .tutorial1 {
      text-align: left;
    }

    .tutorial3 {
      align: left;
      width: 550px;
      padding: 40px 20px 40px;
      background-color: #DAE1F7;
      font-family: "Open Sans";
      font-size: 16px;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }

    .button {
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 30px;  
    }

    .button1 {
      background-color: #000000; /* Black */
      font-family:"Open Sans";
      font-size:14px
    } 

    .button2 {
      background-color: #008CBA; /* Blue */
    }
  </style>

  <div class="tutorial1">
    <div class="tutorial">Review &amp; Sign</div>
    <div class="tutorial"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/644f1595e1464456b3e1895a/6518db34-b32c-4381-aab0-041a151e9f43/keyzii_logo_white+2.png?format=1500w" alt="keyzii logo" style="width:120px" ></div>
  </div>

  <div class="tutorial3">"A very long long long long name" has sent a document for you to review and sign.
    <br><br>
    <button class="button button1">Open Document</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div class= "tutorial4">
    <a style="font-family:'Open Sans'; font-weight: bolder">Document Title</a>
    <br>
    <a style="font-family:'Open Sans'; font-weight: regular"><b>Signers:</b> email address, email address, email address</a>
    <br><br>
    <a style="font-family:'Open Sans'; font-weight: regular;">Please click on the button above to open, review and sign the document.
    <br>Make sure you have read and understood keyzii sign details below.</a>
    <br><br>
    <button class="button button1">Call Now</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <hr style="width:37%;text-align:left;margin-left:0; color:#A4A4A4">
  <br><br>
  <div class= "tutorial4">
    <a style="font-family:'Open Sans';font-size: 25px; font-weight: bolder">keyzii sign</a> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <a style="font-family:'Open Sans'; font-weight: regular">About keyzii sign and how it works
    <br>If you need to xyz<br>Do not share info</a>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I figured out the font ref; that was easy. The mobile responsive is the real issue now

Comment: Media queries is the best place to start for responsive.

Answer (score -1):

You have elements that are 600px and are looking at it on a device that is only approximately 350px! Therefore, you need to add something like `max-width:100%` to those elements.

Second, some email clients including some types of Gmail accounts (e.g. Gmail IMAP/POP) do not allow `<style>` blocks. Therefore, instead of using styles there, inline them.

For the fonts, go to Google Fonts and use the code there. But note the availability of webfonts for email here: https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/. However, Google already have Roboto and Open Sans installed. So your font stack will need to be `"Open Sans", sans-serif;` so that email programs default to the right type of font.